# what is the sonoma meaning in macOS new release 14 operation system

Tags: macos

In the macOS 14 operation system, it name macOS sonoma. I was wondering the meaning of sonoma. I just found a California Villege called this name:

> Sonoma (/səˈnoʊmə/) is a city in Sonoma County, California, United
> States, located in the North Bay region of the San Francisco Bay Area.

does this macOS operation system name come from here?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoma,_California

Comment: If you already accessed Wikipedia, you may have found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sonoma as well which actually answers this :-)

Comment: This is a perfect question for Apple SE. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since macOS 10.9 (Mavericks), the names of all OS versions are places in California.

Comment: I think the first few were all specifically mountains [Mavericks through to High Sierra], then they shifted to towns. My California geography isn't great. Mojave is a desert, I know that much ;) so that was likely the transition point.

Comment: That intresting, I did not know this before.

Comment: Ah, Mojave is a desert, Big Sur is an area of spectacular coastline & Catalina is an island. After that they shifted to actual towns. I've actually driven past/through Big Sur  on Highway 1 [PCH] & stayed in Monterey, where there's a famous jazz festival, canneries & pelicans - way back in the 90s when I went to California for a month [I'm from the UK] & drove the PCH from Tijuana to San Fransisco [in a red soft-top Mustang… some things you just have to do;) but most of the others I'd never heard of until Apple used them for OS names.

Comment: @Tetsujin Isn't Mavericks a surfing beach?

Comment: So it is. You can hover the codenames in this list to see a thumbnail description of them all - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Timeline_of_releases